# If $u$ has a weak derivative and $f$ is $C^1$ does $fu$ have a weak derivative (fractional Sobolev space and weak time derivatives)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set.

Let $s \in (0,1)$ and $H^s(\Omega) := W^{s,2}(\Omega).$ Let $f \in C^1([0,T]\times \Omega)$ and $u \in L^2(0,T;H^s(\Omega))$ with weak derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-s}(\Omega))$. We also have that $f$ and $\nabla f$ (the spatial gradient) are uniformly bounded in time and space.

Does it follow that $(fu)'$ exists and $(fu)' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-s}(\Omega))$?

Any ideas? Maybe there is a reference for this already.

Comment: This is too incomplete to be called an answer, but: Maybe you need $f\in C^{1,1}$ (i.e. the derivative is also bounded)? Roughly speaking, if you take $u \in L^2$ and $f \in L^\infty$, then $fu \in L^2$. Similarly, for a function in $H^1$, you can multiply by $f \in C^{1,1}$ and remain in $H^1$ ($(fu)' = f'u + fu'.$ and since $f' \in L^\infty,$ $f'u \in L^2$, etc.)

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151884/if-u-in-w10-tl2-h1-and-varphi-in-c10-t-times-omega-then-var

Comment: @Baron's comments: The derivative of $f$ is bounded in time. Hence, I don't think that more regularity is necessary. @ Problem. Assume, the product rule is valid, then you should find $(fu)'= f'u+fu'$. In this expression each term is well defined and lies in your desires space (not sure about the boundary of $f$ btw). Hence, you should be able to obtain you result simply by approximation. You only need mollification in time of $u'$. Away from the boundary points $0,T$ you will be able to show that $(u_h)'=(u')_h$, where $h$ denotes mollification.